# Selected Item from Combobox should be deleted from list and update tree

Tags: c#, winforms, list, combobox

I'm a beginner in programming c#.
I'm working on a project (Winforms, c#) where you can add, update and delete books.
These books are shown in a tree, sorted by the author.
I have a Combobox, which contains the books from the list. I want to select a book and delete it by clicking on the delete button. 
But I have no idea, how to get the selected Item from the Combobox and delete it from the list.
I tried something like:

```
private void OnClickDeleteBook_DelDialog(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BookList.RemoveAt(comboxDelBook.SelectedIndex);            
    }
```

But it doesn't work.
How can I delete the selected Book from the list and update the tree afterwards?

Comment: `SelectedIndex`would give you a number,the index of the selected item in the scope of the `ComboBox`. Try with `SelectedItem`, although it depends of how you are populating the tree and the combobox

Answer (score 0):

Does the Winforms Comboboxelement even receive a update or Listchanged or something? The View hast to know, that she has to update the combobox because the list has changed.

Did you bind the list to the comboboxelement?

Is a Changenotificiation event fired on listupdate or maybe can you use an ObservableCollection?